# Plotting isotherms with Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a file with data like this

```
#temp density press
1.0   0.03    0.001
1.0   0.03    0.002
.
.
.
```

The first column is the temperature. I would like to plot isotherms in state equation graph [fashion](https://www.brainkart.com/article/Gaseous-state---Critical-phenomena_2744/)

This means making a graph u 2:3 with multiple lines, each line corresponding to a value of the temperature. When I searched how to do this I found everyone made like a heat map with colors. I don't want that, I want just the lines.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I may not understand your data format correctly, it sounds like you want something like this.  To plot the lines that have temp=1.0

```
  plot DATA using ($1==1.0 ? $2 : NaN) : 3 with lines
```

If you know the exact values of the temperatures in advance you could string a set of these together into a single plot. Suppose temperatures 1.0 100.0 200.0

```
  set style data lines
  plot DATA using ($1==1.0 ? $2 : NaN) : 3, \
         '' using ($1==100.0 ? $2 : Nan) : 3, \
         '' using ($1==200.0 ? $2 : Nan) : 3
```

A better option is to separate the blocks of data in your input file with a blank line wherever the temperature changes.  Then you can catch each separate temperature block in a separate line with a distinct color or dash pattern:

```
  set style data lines
  plot for [block=0:*] DATA index=block using 2:3
```